# Add a reference to a project in entity framework project

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, visual-studio-2012, nuget, nuget-package

I have two entity framework solutions in Visual Studio 2012. I used Nuget to download EF5 on both.

In first solution/project I created a class library and I want to add it to the project in solution 2.
I am not sure how to add it. I noticed that there is a folder

```
..\..\packages\EntityFramework.5.0.0\lib\net45
```

Two questions:

1. Where is the folder(packages) coming from? (Just a guess it is from Nuget but not sure..)
2. How to add the reference?(Browser to this folder to locate it or using Nuget?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: It's one folder up to your project folder and actually it's beside your solution, it has been downloaded from http://wwww.nuget.org website.

Second: Add it through NuGet(by clicking on project and select Manage Packages or using the command line power-shell Install-Package) and it will manage it to not download it again and reference to the same file

Comment: I saw there is "Enable Nuget package restore"...Should I enable it?

Comment: It will do another useful thing, but there is an item named Manage Packages, when you click on Project. Actually you clicked on Solution and by enabling Nuget package Restore you would be able to ship the code to another guy without packages(the downloaded dlls) and Visual Studio(to be exact NuGet will do that) will download the missing packages upon compilation.

Comment: EF is a DLL, DLL is Dynamic Link Library which is the extension if most file names downloaded as package.

Comment: I meant the dll I created in solution 1. I haven't seen it in the window.

Comment: Do you mean that the folder is empty, if it's the case, probably a power-shell script checks for existence of dll in GAC or a specific installation path and not download it. Go to project references and click on EF reference and select properties, you can see the full path of referenced dll.